# Python to remove timestamps in transcript based on certain condition

Tags: python, txt

I have a transcript txt file with timestamps ok, so suppose there are 2 timestamps occuring within 50 words, so what i want is to remove 2nd timestamps occuring within 50 words and retain next timestamps after 50 words and again check whether there is occurance within 50 words or not and if yes remove that one and maintain the sequence.
I want to do all this in python please advise.
#python #vba

I'm not getting how to approach this?

Comment: this is relatively straight forward, but what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: helpful idea.  select a language, post example of text file content. how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask